# Javascript 3D library that can be easy to use

Tags: javascript, 3d

Just found an interesting application here:
http://mydeco.com/3d-planner/

I hear they use Javascript for making this (http://thenextweb.com/apps/2010/05/05/3d-room-planner-mydeco-aims-american-homes-ditches-flash/). Several 3D libraries (like WebGL) don’t run well in every browser, but this room planner works fine in most browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera).

Does someone know what Javascript 3D library that can make something like that? I’m really new to something like this, not sure where to start. Honestly, I expect something that can be easy to use.

Or perhaps someone has experiences or suggestions about this? Please share if you do.

Thank you!

Comment: ... WAY past cool, but did you look at the source of one of the scenes?

Comment: Yes, and without getting any idea about it :).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at three.js? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js

It uses either `<canvas>`, `<svg>`, or WebGL, so it should run in any "modern" browser, including IE9 (but not, I think, earlier versions).

Comment: Thanks for replying, nrabinowitz. I tried its demos, but several of them don't work in my browser (Chrome 10). Is there other libraries that offer better compatibility?

Comment: I don't know of any others that you couldn't find just as easily by googling http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+3d :). My guess is that the current state of the art will require a lot of cross-browser testing and tweaking no matter what library you use.

Comment: Well, I have done it before but honestly it isn't easy for me to choose one of those 3D libraries :(. Just still wonder what myDeco uses to make it. Thanks again for the opinion, anyway.

Comment: Three.js is awesome, but webgl is a hard dependency, so it won't work on iOS.